# Poor insert performance when inserting records into a table with with GUID non-clustered PK

Tags: sql-server

I'm benchmarking the insert performance of SQL Server 2017 on a table with nonclustered primary key (GUID) and an additional clustered index (int). While I expected some performance degradation comparing to PK of autoincrementing ints, the metrics I'm getting don't seem reasonable - the insert to the table with GUID PK takes literally 70 times longer.

Tables:

```
[Table1]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, <-- clustered PK
    [Prop_s1] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Prop_s2] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    ...
    [Prop_b3] [BIT] NULL,
    [Prop_n3] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL
)

[Table2]
(
    [Id] [UNIQUEIDENTIFIER] NOT NULL, <-- non-clustered PK
    [Prop_s1] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    [Prop_s2] [NVARCHAR](MAX) NULL,
    ...
    [Prop_b3] [BIT] NULL,
    [Prop_n3] [DECIMAL](18, 2) NULL,
    [ClusterId] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL, <-- clustered
)
```

Queries look like

```
Insert into Table (....)
    select ....
    union all
    select ....
```

Id's for Table2 are generated on client side.

Both tables are otherwise identical in structure.

I can insert 10k records in about 550-600ms with autoincrementing int PK.
With guid keys, it takes about 35 **seconds** per 10k rows.

Comment: What did you set the fill factor to on the index?

Comment: Fill factor only matters "When an index is created or rebuilt".  For an index on a random GUID the constant filling and splitting will keep the index pages on average about 65% full. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/specify-fill-factor-for-an-index?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: @BenThul Whatever the default is.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft - I'm aware of that. Indexes on GUIDs are generally not great but it would be exacerbated if the index had been created on existing data and the full factor set to, say, 100.

Answer (score 3):

Inserting random GUIDs into a non-clustered PK has all the same problems as inserting random GUIDs into a clustered PK, just to a lesser degree.  Each row is placed on a "random" page, and the pages fill up and must be split.

And with a the non-clustered PK you have an unnecessary index to maintain.

It's better to have the Clustered Index on the Guid and [NEWSEQUENTIALID()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) or client-side sequential GUID generation.

Client-side sequential GUID generation requires re-ordering some of the bytes to align to how SQL Server sorts GUIDs.  In C# on Windows, it looks like this:

```
  public class SQLGuidUtil
  {
      [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
      static extern int UuidCreateSequential(out Guid guid);

      public static Guid NewSequentialId()
      {
        Guid guid;
        UuidCreateSequential(out guid);
        var s = guid.ToByteArray();
        var t = new byte[16];
        t[3] = s[0];
        t[2] = s[1];
        t[1] = s[2];
        t[0] = s[3];
        t[5] = s[4];
        t[4] = s[5];
        t[7] = s[6];
        t[6] = s[7];
        t[8] = s[8];
        t[9] = s[9];
        t[10] = s[10];
        t[11] = s[11];
        t[12] = s[12];
        t[13] = s[13];
        t[14] = s[14];
        t[15] = s[15];
        return new Guid(t);
      }
  }
```

Comment: I do have a clustered index on the table (ClusterId), so why would it be placed to a random page? Also I did try using sequential guids (RT.Comb) with similar results.

Comment: 1) The fragmentation and page splitting still happens on the BTree for the non-clustered PK.  That structure just has the Guid and the Clustered PK.  2) Are you sure you used the SQL Server Comb GUIDS with the bytes swapped?  If so can you post a short repro?

Comment: I've tried RT.Comb implementation and the code above, with similar results. Posted the repo here: https://github.com/Thinkhoop/SqlServerGuidPKPOC.

Comment: Cloned and ran.  I don’t think testing with huge UNION ALL queries is valid.  They take too long to parse and compile.  A single parameterized query, SqlBulkCopy or Table Valued Parameters would be better.

Comment: Maybe, but they're essentially same queries, the only difference being is guid vs ints. Unless much of the time is spent parsing out the guids from the query...

Comment: Not really.  You're _repeating_ the same SQL batch multiple times in the first two cases.  And in any case the run time is mostly query compilation, so you aren't measuring the difference between the key insert performance.  It's a rounding error.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Tried SqlBulkCopy and TVP - they're significantly faster. Thank you!
BTW, I tried the NewSequentialId method above and looks like it's actually slower than inserting random GUIDs.

Comment: Sequential Keys _can_ be slower than random keys, so long as your data fits in memory.  With sequential keys you have latch contention on the insert pages, so in a multi-threaded environment on a small table you can achieve higher insert rates with random keys.

Answer (score 0):

try using NEWSEQUENTIALID() instead of newid() to generate the unique identifier. Typically I would put a IDENTITY column if you have lots of inserts happening on that table

Comment: It worth putting a bit of explanation here as to why `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` will have a benefit over `NEWID()` here.

Comment: This would defeat the reason why I'm using guids, which is to generate ID's on the client side. Having said that, I did try sequential IDs, client-generated, with similar results.